# Unable to apply theme to WordPress Network Site install

Tags: multisite, admin, subdomains

I'm using media temple with a fresh install of WordPress in network mode. **With subdomains off.**

```
define( 'SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', false );
```

I've followed Media Temple's [*wildcard configuration](http://wiki.mediatemple.net/w/%28dv%29%3aSetup_WordPress_network_with_subdomains) (not that I think it matters) and I'm finding that when I create a new site nothing is working except it displaying a very basic page.

Any ideas what would cause this?

http://shallbetterdesigns.com/test/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, it is because you set up wildcard subdomains. You don't need to set them up if you just want to use subfolders. Because of this, `http://test.shallbetterdesigns.com/wp-content/themes/twentyeleven/style.css` can be found, but `http://www.shallbetterdesigns.com/test/wp-content/themes/twentyeleven/style.css` can't.

Comment: I went ahead a changed the wildcard ServerAlias *.shallbetterdesigns.com to www.shallbetterdesigns.com I deleted the network site and it seems to still be missing the theme.

Comment: www.shallbetterdesigns.com is serving me the Apache test page. I am not a server person at all and can't advise you on what exactly to do, but I would carefully undo what you did for the wildcard configuration, not just change things around.

Comment: I was able to resolve the issue. I had to remake the site from scratch after deleting the .conf information.